# Hyperreal probability density?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, nonstandard-analysis

I'm fairly new to the subject of hyperreal numbers and I'm wondering if there exists an infinitesimal number $a$ such that (in some reasonable sense) 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a=1$$
?

In other words: Is there a uniform (hyperreal valued) probability distribution on the natural numbers?

I hope the question is posed clearly enough.

Comment: Intuitively I think it does not exist. Let $a>0$ be an infinitesimal number. Then, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $na$ is infinitesimal, i.e. $na \leq \frac{1}{n}$, so I don't think that $\lim_n na$ (according it exists) can ever reach $1$.

Comment: If such an $a$ exists then not as real number. So it cannot be linked to probabilities. These are by definition functions to $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sure. I'm looking for a generalized notion of probability measures.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a = 1$ is true for every standard $a$; therefore by the transfer principle it is true for every nonstandard $a$ as well. However, if $H$ is an unlimited integer, then we have the (hyper)finite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{H} \frac{1}{H} = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at chapter 5 of the paper "Non-Archimedean Probability": http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1524v1.pdf

In section 5.2 you can find a non-archimedean uniform probability for the natural numbers defined in the setting of nonstandard analysis. Since that probability is uniform, every singleton has infinitesimal probability $a>0$, and the "sum over the natural numbers" of $a$ is indeed equal to $1$.

The notions of nonstandard analysis and the concept of "sum over the natural numbers" are introduced in chapters 3 and 4 of the same paper.